# TensorFlow 2.12 GPU Utilisation with CUDA 11.8 - Unsuccessful GPU utilisation during training even though it shown to be available

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Update: Apparently the GPU was being used, only at 30% of its max capability for some reason, assuming its due to the simple network's complexity and batch sizes.

[Fluctuations during GPU Performance while the code is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxQPf.png)

I'm using TensorFlow 2.12, with CUDA 11.8 and cudNN 8.6, I have installed the packages as indicated in their respective documentations ([TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2) & [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local)). I managed to successfully utilise the GPU during testing of the package within my .py file using:

```
in: print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
```

```
out: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Although, I cannot get my training to be run with the GPU, I am sure that I am missing a significant point in activating it, such as how one can transfer the data running through the model from CPU to GPU using ".to(device)" function in PyTorch.

I have looked up at the documentation, although could not spot anything.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TensorFlow counterpart for the PyTorch operation you have mentioned and for your use here, should be [tf.device](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement).

In general, TensorFlow will **automatically add the operations** to the available devices according to the function being used.

As you have rightly mentioned, with `tf.config.list_physical_devices()` you'll be able to see the devices your runtime is using (CPU/GPU/TPU).

With `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` you can find out to which devices your operations and tensors are assigned.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
```

Output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

For manually assigning the CPU,

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)  

with tf.device('/CPU:0'): 

  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]) 

  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
```

Output:

```
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

For using the same with GPU,

```
with tf.device('/GPU:0'): 

  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]) 

  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]]
```

Output:

```
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

For more information on **manual device placement**, please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement).

Comment: Ah, I gave a long break and coming back to this comment really helped me a lot. Thank you.